# Keep both structure.sql and schema.rb up to date in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I'm using a  postgres feature that rails schema.rb file doesn't support so I've set `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` to ensure that all aspects of my database schema are recorded.  However, when I set this option rails seems to stop updating the schema.rb file.

Since schema.rb is far far easier to read and I really only need structure.sql to capture the array_to_string function needed to generate a certain fulltext index I'd like to have migrations automatically update schema.rb as well as structure.sql.

Is there any way to get rails to update both when I run db:migrate without (as I've been doing) changing the config option by hand and then rerunning db:migrate?

Comment: Have you considered going into `psql` and saying `\d table_name` instead? The output is pretty readable and collects everything in one place (unlike `structure.sql`).

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is an easy way to have this automatically generated each time I run db:migrate.  If I knew how to hook into db:migrate, I could write a script that ran through all tables in the db and run that command, but I bet it would be easier to hook into it and run db:migrate twice, once with each value of config.active_record.schema_format.  My issue is understanding rails internals enough to do either not getting info from psql.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, I'm being an idiot.  There are rake tasks db:schema:dump and db:structure:dump.  All I have to do is to create a new task that has dependencies on db:migrate and both db:structure:dump db:schema:dump or just run them both on the command line.